# Ubuntu: purpose of home directory files and folders

Tags: files, home-directory

I've just installed the latest version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I would like to ask, what is the purpose of the examples.desktop

text file my home directory? Also, what is the intended purpose

of the folders Public and Templates?

Thanks,

John Goche

Comment: http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-add-templates-in-ubuntu-context-menu-tip/

Answer (score 2):

- `Example.desktop` it is a link to a folder containing some examples of what you can do with Ubuntu. I believe is similar to `Sample` folders of other legacy OS.
- The `Public` folder is a container for files and contents you like to share with other users of the system.
- The `Template` folder is the default container for your your documents templates (text, audio, spreadsheets, etc.). It is the one that is parsed by default when you right click `Nautilus` file manager and hover on the `New Document` menu item.